# XML deserializing fails in C# using xsd gen

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML file. I have used xsd to generate the structure.
It looks like the file is not getting deserialized or something because I get NULL values when hovering over the data object in debugging mode. Any help with this issue is appriciated. I want to be able to looping through all the "Functional Blocks" in the structure.

XML containing data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shapes>
  <FunctionalBlocks>
    <FunctionalBlock uid="{446C5C15-FF16-491D-910B-B8F9F4D90960}" name="1FT001">
      <props>
        <prop name="Typical or Mode" />
        <prop name="Function Template Type">MA</prop>
        <prop name="Node">01</prop>
        <prop name="System (Tag)">1</prop>
        <prop name="Instrumentation Identification (Tag)">FT</prop>
        <prop name="Sequence Number (Tag)">001</prop>
        <prop name="Comment">Production</prop>
        <prop name="SAS System">C</prop>
        <prop name="EffectList" />
        <prop name="Shape Type">FunctionBlock</prop>
      </props>
      <pos left="6.220472" top="18.425196" right="7.165354" bottom="17.795275" />
      <connects>
        <In />
        <Out />
        <Undirected />
      </connects>
    </FunctionalBlock>
    <FunctionalBlock uid="{2C9BB4F3-FC87-4866-8EA8-48076AFDCF29}" name="1HV001">
      <props>
        <prop name="Typical or Mode" />
        <prop name="Function Template Type">SBE</prop>
        <prop name="Node">01</prop>
        <prop name="System (Tag)">1</prop>
        <prop name="Instrumentation Identification (Tag)">HV</prop>
        <prop name="Sequence Number (Tag)">001</prop>
        <prop name="Comment" />
        <prop name="SAS System">C</prop>
        <prop name="EffectList" />
        <prop name="Shape Type">FunctionBlock</prop>
      </props>
      <pos left="7.559055" top="18.425196" right="8.503937" bottom="17.795275" />
      <connects>
        <In />
        <Out />
        <Undirected />
      </connects>
    </FunctionalBlock>
  </FunctionalBlocks>
</shapes>
```

The code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace NCG
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp), new XmlRootAttribute("shapes"));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\SCD.xml", FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader xtr = XmlReader.Create(fs);
            shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp data = (shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp)serializer.Deserialize(xtr);
            xtr.Close();

        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.81.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class shapes
    {

        private shapesFunctionalBlocks[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FunctionalBlocks", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public shapesFunctionalBlocks[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class shapesFunctionalBlocks
    {

        private shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlock[] functionalBlockField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FunctionalBlock", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlock[] FunctionalBlock
        {
            get
            {
                return this.functionalBlockField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.functionalBlockField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlock
    {

        private shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp[][] propsField;

        private shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPos[] posField;

        private shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockConnects[] connectsField;

        private string uidField;

        private string nameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("prop", typeof(shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp[][] props
        {
            get
            {
                return this.propsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.propsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("pos", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPos[] pos
        {
            get
            {
                return this.posField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.posField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("connects", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockConnects[] connects
        {
            get
            {
                return this.connectsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.connectsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string uid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uidField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uidField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPropsProp
    {

        private string nameField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockPos
    {

        private string leftField;

        private string topField;

        private string rightField;

        private string bottomField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string left
        {
            get
            {
                return this.leftField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.leftField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string top
        {
            get
            {
                return this.topField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.topField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string right
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rightField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rightField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string bottom
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bottomField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bottomField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class shapesFunctionalBlocksFunctionalBlockConnects
    {

        private string inField;

        private string outField;

        private string undirectedField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string In
        {
            get
            {
                return this.inField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.inField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Out
        {
            get
            {
                return this.outField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.outField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Undirected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.undirectedField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.undirectedField = value;
            }
        }
    }




}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make this work by copying your xml and doing EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes. There must be some problem with your generated class.

With this new class definition you must make sure you change the button click event to use the new class if you change its name:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class shapes
{

    private shapesFunctionalBlock[] functionalBlocksField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("FunctionalBlock", IsNullable = false)]
    public shapesFunctionalBlock[] FunctionalBlocks
    {
        get
        {
            return this.functionalBlocksField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.functionalBlocksField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class shapesFunctionalBlock
{

    private shapesFunctionalBlockProp[] propsField;

    private shapesFunctionalBlockPos posField;

    private shapesFunctionalBlockConnects connectsField;

    private string uidField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("prop", IsNullable = false)]
    public shapesFunctionalBlockProp[] props
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.propsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public shapesFunctionalBlockPos pos
    {
        get
        {
            return this.posField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.posField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public shapesFunctionalBlockConnects connects
    {
        get
        {
            return this.connectsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.connectsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class shapesFunctionalBlockProp
{

    private string nameField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class shapesFunctionalBlockPos
{

    private decimal leftField;

    private decimal topField;

    private decimal rightField;

    private decimal bottomField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal left
    {
        get
        {
            return this.leftField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.leftField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal top
    {
        get
        {
            return this.topField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.topField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal right
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rightField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rightField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal bottom
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bottomField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bottomField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class shapesFunctionalBlockConnects
{

    private object inField;

    private object outField;

    private object undirectedField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public object In
    {
        get
        {
            return this.inField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.inField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Out
    {
        get
        {
            return this.outField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.outField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Undirected
    {
        get
        {
            return this.undirectedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.undirectedField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

With above class, and deserialization code slightly modified:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(shapes), new XmlRootAttribute("shapes"));
FileStream fs = new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader xtr = XmlReader.Create(fs);
shapes data = (shapes)serializer.Deserialize(xtr);
xtr.Close();
```

`data` is now contains an array of type `shapesFunctionalBlock`.
You can access them like:

```
shapesFunctionalBlock foo = data.FunctionalBlocks[0];
shapesFunctionalBlock foo2 = data.FunctionalBlocks[1];
//...etc.
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm not able to use foreach statement on the deserialized object. Do you have any thoughts how to make it enumarble?

Comment: @Snovva1 see Edit for accessing the array.

Comment: Yes, had no problem accessing the data using for loop. I tried something like this: foreach(FunctionalBlock fb in data)
                            ..........

did not work because the classes is no enumarble i think.